# How do I introspectively discover defined directives (or controllers, etc) in an included Angular module?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, code-injection, angularjs-injector

I'm architecting a project where we have one module acting as our shell, handling global styles, navigation, etc, with an `ng:view` getting filled by directives provided by our second module with all the pages.

I would really like to find a way for the shell to inspect the pages module, discovering the nav structure dynamically, rather than defining it by hand or having every page inject itself both in the `pages` module AND to the `shell` module. On its own, the injector doesn't seem to like doing that.

**EDIT**

As clarification: while I have a fabulous workaround with a pagesProvider service, I am still looking for an answer as to whether Angular 1.2.x has a mechanism to introspect modules.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly: at the end all `injected` *objects* (like services, filters, controllers) will end up in *one big bag* (something like *global namespace*). So it is enough to inject each `page` into `pages` and `pages` into `shell`. (mind the possibility of name-conflicts.)

Secondly: at this time, there is no support for lazy loading of modules. So you should know all your modules *beforehand*, so there is actually no need to check which *objects* are present and which not, as either there are all of them or the application has not started at all.

I do not know  what you actually mean by discovering `nav structure` and how it will be defined. But, what you can do is:

1. in each page-module  define a `constant` in which the `nav structure` of this page will be stored.
2. access this `constant` from `shell` when needed. If you need to know dynamically the `id`of active page, just set this information somewhere -- probably as `value` -- when the pages gets activated.

Some alternatives:

1. define one global `hash-map` from `page-id`s to `page-nav-structure`s.
2. use a common service that will be injected to each page and will be used to register pages and all related information about it.

Comment: Not lazy loading modules - all are in at build time. I'm not unsure whether the module has loaded - separation of concerns means the shell module knows that the page module exists, but doesn't know what directives are in it (this is a rapidly evolving page structure, with new pages added a couple times a week).

The preferred contract is that pages defines some pages, and their position in the nav - ideally, encoded in the directive name. The (dev) usability goal is to not need to input that info twice.

Comment: @DavidSouther I understand now better. So what is wrong with using constants or separate service to perform this task? (you can use directive-name as a key)

Comment: I came to that conclusion about 20 minutes after your comment, but haven't had time to implement. I think what I'll do is (for that project only) define a new function on module called "page" which registers the name in both the directive and the constants. Thanks for getting my thoughts flowing! (I'll accept tomorrow after I implement ;) )

Comment: @DavidSouther Glad that it was helpful:-)

Comment: just to clarify, I haven't accepted this answer, as it does not answer the actual question, as to whether introspection is possible in Angular at this time :)